# How can I identify this single phase AC induction motor?

Tags: ac, identification, induction-motor

I have an AC motor with 7 different wires connecting to it, and I'd like to identify how the windings are configured. The wires are:

- Red
- Orange
- Yellow
- Blue
- Black
- White
- Yellow+Green

What I've been able to gather so far is that:

- Yellow+Green is protective earth and connected to the motor housing and nothing else
- White is directly connected to mains neutral
- Live mains is switched directly onto Yellow, Blue, Black, or nothing to provide 4 different speed settings
- There's a capacitor across Red and Orange

These are the resistances I've measured between the different wires in Ohms:

|  | Orange | Yellow | Blue | Black | White |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Red** | 34 | 29 | 23 | 17.3 | 33.2 |
| **Orange** |  | 28.6 | 22.6 | 16.7 | 0.3 |
| **Yellow** |  |  | 6.1 | 12 | 28 |
| **Blue** |  |  |  | 6 | 22.1 |
| **Black** |  |  |  |  | 16.4 |

(Note that the measurements between White and the other terminals might be slightly high. They were made from the neutral pin of the AC cord of the device for convenience, whereas everything else was measured directly on the connectors on the motor.)

Given that information, how would I go about identifying the motor's configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: what markings are on the motor?

Comment: @jsotola There's no visible markings on the motor. I believe it to be https://hessaire.com/collections/mc37m-mc37v-m150-parts/products/mc37v-mc37mlater-than-2019-motor-6375100 which says 115V / 2.4A.

Comment: Another thing I noticed about the motor is that it makes a clicking sound once per revolution when spun slowly by hand. That sound disappears as the fan gets up to higher speeds. Maybe that's some kind of starter mechanism that disengages once centrifugal forces are high enough?

Comment: Any capacitor built in or connected to it?

Comment: @winny There's no built-in capacitor I could identify. There's an external capacitor between Red and Orange.

Comment: @FlorianRagwitz I think I'd see the same setup on any common house fan I opened up, that has low, medium, and high speed settings. I'd expect to see a switch with four wires going to it and I'd expect to see one capacitor, if I opened up any random fan like that. Is this any different? Have you tried to just open up a working AC fan controller box, yet?

Comment: @jonk What's the coil configuration in the common 3-speed house fans you've opened up?

Comment: Is there any centrifugal switch which connects red or orange to anything else if you spin it fast enough or operate it manually?

Comment: @winny see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574940/how-can-i-identify-this-single-phase-ac-induction-motor#comment1506306_574940 for all I've discovered so far regarding that.

Comment: @FlorianRagwitz I don't recall counting them. I suppose I'd need to open another one and cut through the bound cable of 16 gauge wires (which are LOTS bigger than the little motor wires) and see what they are tied into. These cheap floor fans mostly don't even have ball bearing races so I usually do the minimums in repairing them or else toss them out. The motors I do tear down are only expensive ones; and not the same thing. For example, a 1970 bathroom ceiling fan motor from an expensive supplier whose replacement was US$400. I tore that thing all the way down to its windings and fixed it.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with this investigation?

Comment: @Andyaka A better understanding of how motors work, and gathering enough information to determine what my options for continuous speed control of that particular motor might be.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiHFA3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

my reasoning was

- the capacitor connectes to the cross-phase coil
- ignoring the capacitor there will be no loops
- wherever there is a lowest resistasnce those two nodes must be connected.

Comment: Which suggests the four speeds are (fastest) Black, Blue, Yellow, Off.

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know what this configuration is called? What do you think the purpose of L6 is? I'm wondering if it's just a measurement error or the resistance of the wires leading to the motor rather than an actual coil.

Comment: if L6 is measurement error it's a systematic error. necause it's consitent across all the other measurements which show slightly higher resistance to orange than to white.  it could be a sentrifugal switch but the figure seems a bit high for a switch,

Comment: Thank you. Would you happen to know how I might be able to differentiate between a systematic error and there being a low-resistance coil? I'm also curious where the centrifugal switch would fit into that schematic. Is the idea that it disconnects the capacitor once it's up to speed? What practical effect does that have?